# bootstrap panel collapse causing fade in

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the collapse property for a series of panels on a website.  Instead of just adding text, I am adding an image along with a title and information about what a viewer will see if they click on the panel.  I am trying to make this responsive and I noticed when I start shrinking the web browser the info of what the viewer will see is getting thrown under the image.  My code looks like this:

```
<div class="panel-group" id=:"accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <a href="#content" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
          <img src="img/foo.jpg" class=col-md-2 img-responsive" alt="yeah">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <h4>hello</h4>
            <p>World</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <!--content -->
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- and so on and so on -->
</div>
```

doing this allows the panels to be responsive to the shrinking of the browser, but when I click to collapse and show the panel body, it is causing a jQuery fadeIn effect saw opposed to automatically showing the content.  It's not that it looks terrible, but the fadeIn is slow and I do not like how it is working.

Any help would be gratefully received.  Thanks.

Comment: I messed up when typing the question out.  I did put the id on the div class panel-collapse

Comment: is it just a typo in the question? `class=col-md-2 img-responsive"` should have a `"` after the `class=`

Comment: and also the `:` on the first line after `id=`

Comment: can you any custom css you are using for accordions to this bootply please.. it appears to be working as expected with no fade http://www.bootply.com/OIbrZiWeUi (added `class="row"` to the collapse link)

Comment: yeah, there are no typos in the file I created.  I messed up when typing the post.  sorry for that.  Everything's correct but i am still getting a weird fade in property

Comment: can you update my above pasted bootply with any additional theme/custom css you've added so that we can debug your working environment please.. as i mentioned.. it works as expected there

Comment: no custom theme nor any other css.  That's why I don't understand why the fade is being caused.

Comment: can you tell if the fade is coming from js or css? (inspect the element and see if the fade values are being supplied inline, if so they must be coming from some JS)